# Struts & Jersey Servlets with JSP & Webpack Front End

Tags: java, rest, webpack, jersey-2.0

we currently have a struts 1.2 web application with casual JSP web pages. We want to migrate our application to Rest service web application with a webpack project front end.

As this will be a migration process where old pages will be served under oracle weblogic server and new ones will be served under a different production server.

We will still hold our backend server to serve restful apis.

The problem is when I call a api from webpack project it creates a new session and I can not use the session data of logged user.

I created a singleton hashmap to store session object where I can send key to new pages which enables to get session data but it seemed wrong and I wanted to ask if there is another way to implement this.

Edit: I tried to make it more visible with this picture[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v21d.png)

Regards,

Comment: give more details ... is front end stack still JSP? ... normally the front end will have a token <==> cookie tuple aspect that corresponds to User/Session on the back end. Both token/ cookies have independent expiry on front end ... And as long as front-end token exists it can be used GET || POST to acquire both user & session from the back end.

Comment: Currently there are all Jsp and we will create corresponding new pages in a new Vue.js webpack application which will be working like a SPA.  We will work page by page and move from jsp to Vue views. After a period of time there won't be any jsp pages left.  But till that time users will be moving back and forth between old jsp pages served on weblogic and new spa application server on another web server.

Comment: sounds like a general architecture question involving front-end , back-end mgmt. of user sessions where the dtls are ( front-is-Vue, backend is some New app Server which u did not mention but that is critical to the question of sessionMgmt.  When u know what the new appServer is going to be , you will need the Docs there on user/session mgmt and then u will need to understand how to get VUE/SPA to collaborate in its mgmt of client side  tokens/ sessions/ user mgmt.

Comment: I added an explanatory image I hope that helps to visualize my situation. Regards

Comment: hmm... more questions u may need answers to ... u have 2 appservers during the migration , both providing session mgmt with NO cross-dependencys... but during migration, u need to design / impose a cross dependency because one or the other of your appServers implementation of sessions MUST be a primary, the other a slave mapped both to its own session AND to the master..  What is your design for bridging or your mapped dependency among the 2 app servers ( WL and new Server) ?? What is ur inventory of all calls all state transitions all DB / IO that need to be aware of the "bridge" layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a Webpack application and publishing a dist folder on Apache which is mapped under the same domain of the parent application. This enabled to move between two different front ends without any problems.

Comment: good job ! I have a just a question, the cookie JSESSIONID provided by the backend webapp was not enought to work with the same session ?

Comment: It would work probably but we still needed to serve applications in the same domain to avoid some security vulnerability risks.Browser doesn't understand or care which application is handling requests as long as they are under same domain. Also no need to move JSESSION manually as it is working out of the box with same domain. And also my company didn't want to have a node server for front end application so we went with the static build way.